# Why is my middle ScrollView not displaying with 3 fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

The bottom fragment and top fragments will display but the middle will not. The problem seems to be in the layout but I don't see where. If I pull out the code for the top fragment completely I get middle and bottom. I am guessing that the top fragment is taking up all of the available space but I modeled it after the bottom fragment that is not doing something like that. Any help would be appreciated.

Container xml

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomPosition"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/topPosition"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    </FrameLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/middleScroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomPosition"
        android:layout_below="@id/topPosition"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainPosition"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </FrameLayout>
    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Top position xml

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tarsiertechnology.wikiquizzi.TimerFragment">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/scoreText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/timerText"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/scoreText"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/scoreText" />


    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/timerBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timerText"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/timerText"
        android:max="30"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Bottom position xml

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.tarsiertechnology.wikiquizzi.AnswerFragment">

    <EditText
        android:hint="@string/answer_hint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/answerEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:text="@string/Check"
        android:id="@+id/checkButton"
        android:onClick="checkAnswer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/answerEditText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nextButton" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/next_question"
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="nextQuestion"
        android:layout_below="@+id/answerEditText"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/answerEditText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/answerEditText" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wanders across this there was nothing wrong with the xml. I was missing the execute pending transactions method from the manager.